# Page Numbers of the Standard Edition on the Margins of the Translation

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

Suppose we translated a classical work (Aristotle’s *Nicomachean Ethics*, for example, or Kant’s *Critique of Pure Reason*) and we want to give the page numbers corresponding to the original text’s standard edition (for Aristotle’s *Nicomachean Ethics*, that would be the Bekker numbers, and for Kant’s *Critique of Pure Reason*, that would be the page numbers of the A and B editions of the *Critique of Pure Reason*) on the margins of our translation. How can we achieve this?

Comment: are you forcing the page breaks to be at the same place (so just need to use the same numbering scheme) or do you want the translation to have natural automatic page breaking but keep a reference of the original page numbers?

Comment: I just want the translation to have natural automatic page breaking but keep a reference of the original page numbers. (The document won't be bilingual.)

Comment: the simplest method would be simply to add `\marginpar{original page 5}` at the point that corresponds to the start of page 5 in the source. But perhaps you are looking for something more?

Comment: \marginpar does not work with reledmac/reledpar. You should use the specific macro of reledmac, described on  §12 of the reledmac handbook

Answer (score 1):

Given renewed interest in this question some days ago, here's an explicit answer that elaborates on comments by David Carlisle and Maïeul Rouquette.

A very simple way to write page numbers in the margin would be with `\marginpar`.

```
ΗΘΙΚΩΝ ΝΙΚΟΜΑΧΕΙΩΝ A.%
\marginpar{1094a}

πᾶσα τέχνη καὶ πᾶσα μέθοδος, ὁμοίως δὲ πρᾶξίς τε καὶ προαίρεσις,
ἀγαθοῦ τινὸς ἐφίεσθαι δοκεῖ:
```

Two problems with `marginpar`:

(1) it doesn't work with `reledmac` – the best tool for critical editions with `LaTeX`;

(2) `marginpar` being a float, you cannot append page numbers to footnotes and other elements – and (as any dedicated reader can clearly see) Kant's *Critique of Pure Reason* is full of page breaks in long footnotes.

### reledmac:

As noted by Maïeul, `reledmac` provides its own, quite flexible, tool for sidenotes: `\ledsidenote` (§ 12 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf)).

*An added bonus*: several sidenotes pertaining to the same line are listed in sequence, with a customizable separator put in *automatically*. This is precious when having more than one numbering, as with the two standard editions of Kant's *Critique* (A and B).

This solves (1), but unfortunately, (2) persists: just as line numbering, `ledsidenote`s is disabled for all footnotes (critical or otherwise).

### marginnote

Pkg `marginnote` does not treat marginal text as a float and thus provides a workaround for footnotes (2). Gone, however, is the elegant automatic arrangement of `ledsidenote`s; marginnotes need more micro-management.

> Note: The margin note will be placed at the current vertical line. This means,
> if you are using two `\marginnote` commands at the same line, they will be put on
> the same place. This is not a bug but a feature!
> (from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/marginnote/marginnote.pdf))

For these reasons, I recommend keeping `\ledsidenote` for general use, to bring in `\marginnote` only where the former fails (in footnotes). This is a setup that works for a hypothetical edition of Kant's *Critique*:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}    % for context-appropriate font scaling (\smaller etc.)

\usepackage{reledmac}
\lineation{page}    
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}      % to avoid a clash with line numbers
\setsidenotesep{ }          % the default is ", "

\newcommand{\KrVpageA}[1]{\textbrokenbar\ledsidenote{\textsmaller[1]{A\,#1}}}
\newcommand{\KrVpageB}[1]{\textbar\ledsidenote{\textsmaller[1]{B\,#1}}}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand{\KrVpageAnote}[1]{\textbrokenbar\marginnote{\textsmaller[1]{A\,#1}}}
\newcommand{\KrVpageBnote}[1]{\textbar\marginnote{\textsmaller[1]{B\,#1}}}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
daß wir nämlich von den Dingen nur das a priori erkennen, was wir selbst in sie legen.%
\footnoteA{Diese dem Naturforscher nachgeahmte Methode ... 
als Gegenstände der \KrVpageBnote{XIX} Sinne und des Verstandes für die Erfahrung}
... den \KrVpageB{XIX} sicheren Gang einer Wissenschaft.
\pend
\bigskip

\pstart
so bedeutet die Vorstellung vom Rau\KrVpageA{27}me gar nichts. 
\KrVpageB{43} Dieses Prädikat wird den Dingen nur insofern beigelegt,
\pend
\bigskip

\pstart
so gilt diese Regel allgemein und ohne Einschränkung. Un\KrVpageB{44}sere 
Erörterungen lehren demnach \KrVpageA{28} die \textit{Realität} 
(d.\,i. die objektive Gültigkeit) des Raumes
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: Kant with line numbering and original editions]